# Google Sheets: Dynamic lookup across two (merged) sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have two external GSheets that are set up as room bookings with a running date in col B and the different rooms ppl can book in col C-AX for Sheet1, C-X for Sheet2, as well as my own Sheet with a list of names (let's call it NameSheet).

Example:

[image: Room Sheet]

Goal: I want to add an extra column in NameSheet that returns all dates **within the next two weeks** in which a person has booked a room as well as the room info. Like this:

[image: Employee list with dates & room info]

I used IMPORTRANGE to import both Sheets into my own Sheet (Merged_Sheet) and then merge them dynamically using a simple query formula:

```
=QUERY({'Sheet1'!A:AX;'Sheet2'!A:AX},"select * where Col1 <>''")
```

(I had to expand Sheet 2 to AX in order to merge them.)

I then set up another sheet (Date_Filter) to dynamically filter on the next two weeks:

```
=filter('Merged_Sheet'!A:AX,'Merged_Sheet'!B:B<=today()+7*1)
```

Finally, I have so far only managed to add a column in my original NameSheet that counts the number of times a there is a partial match on a name in the Merged_Sheet:

```
=countif(Date_Filter!A:AX,"*"&Name&"*")
```

Now I'm stuck on how I can return the dates & room info on a partial match (the name columns in the room sheet are "[First Name] [Last Name]" while the employee sheet is set up as "[Last Name],[First Name]") across an entire sheet. I've tried using regexmatch, filter, contains, and even the query function again, but I keep getting function errors.

I would super appreciate any formula help. :)

Comment: Please, share a minimal reproducible example! Thx in advance.

Comment: Hi Mike, not sure what you mean? Since it's a GSheet I can't attach it as a file, I'm not sure I want to make my Google account public? :D

Comment: Lena, keep in mind that this is a free, volunteer-run site. You've got IMPORTRANGE calls happening and lots of data in several places. Without a link to a spreadsheet already set up as yours is with realistic data, you are expecting that the volunteers here will recreate your sheet from scratch based on your partial details before they could even begin to think about how to solve the problem. And that will be a deterrent to many/most. Whether you choose to share a link to the sheet or not is, of course, up to you; but it's probably the only way you'll be able to get the help you're requesting.

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output